# Shopify Store - Text Right To Left, Left To Right , Based On Language

Tags: html, shopify, direction

I have a Shopify store and I want to change the language direction.
I want to make a store that supports both Arabic and English languages, i found couple of apps that do the translation, but my problem is:
I would like the store to flip its direction and text from Left to right into Right to left whenever i'm using Arabic Language , and vice versa when i choose the English language,
is there something that can make this happen.
PS: I started learning HTML 6 months ago.
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best idea would be to use a theme that supports that. I believe there are many out there.

There could be manythings to change or adapt but in general what you should is

```
<style>
{% if localization.language.iso_code == 'ar' %}
 body {
     direction: rtl;
 }
{% endif %}
</style>
```

This should be put in your head close to where you load your style. (Or if you have a .css.liquid file, there).

PS. I'm not 100% sure about the `iso_code` you have, you might want to debug that value, before applying the code.